# Autorestarting mariadb cluster after node reconnection

Tags: mariadb, columnstore, maxscale, mariadb-columnstore

I use official **mariadb/columnstore** docker image. I run docker compose with MaxScale and try to imitate the situation when one of the msc node is disconnected and connected again. I can see in `mcs cluster status` that dbrm_mode is offline and when I try to make queries from my app I get an error `Lost connection to DDLProc` until I restart cluster with `mcs cluster restart` command. Isn't it suppose to work automatically? What other settings may I need? Is this docker image production ready?

Comment: when the problem occurs what do the logs say? I'm mainly talking about MariaDB error log, but also CMAPI error log and CMAPI access log. These last two are not enabled  by default, so you might need to edit the cmapi_server.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, no modifications to the project, you should be connecting to the cluster through MaxScale. The default port for MaxScale 1 is 3310.

Comment: Yes. I understand. I connect to DB through the 3310 or 3311 ports. I talk about the situation when one of the nodes of mariadb is down and up again. In this case cluster stop working and I need to restart it manually